# Разыменование nullptr

Tags: c++, указатели

Что происходит при разыменовании `nullptr`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 9):

Разыменование `nullptr` есть undefined behaviour.

Это значит, что компилятор имеет право предполагать, что эта ситуация никогда не случится, и обрабатывать её как ему вздумается. Отсюда следует, что если в вашей программе есть разыменование `nullptr`, то компилятор имеет право произвести **любой** код, никаких обязательств перед вами или гарантий нет.

В лучшем случае ваша программа просто крешнется. В худшем — будет вести себя необъяснимым странным образом.

---

Вот пример, упрощённый из реального критического бага в ядре Линукса [GNU/Linux, как говорит RMS]. (Украдено [отсюда](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html).)

```
void contains_null_check(int *P) {
  int dead = *P;
  if (P == 0)
    return;
  *P = 4;
}
```

В этом примере кажется, что код проверяет указатель на `nullptr`. Если оптимизатор сначала проведёт *удаление мёртвого кода*, а затем *удаление бессмысленных проверок*, наш код превратится вот во что:

```
// после удаления мёртвого кода
void contains_null_check_stage1(int *P) {
  //int dead = *P;     // неиспользуемая переменная, убрано оптимизатором
  if (P == 0)
    return;
  *P = 4;
}
```

и затем:

```
// после удаления бессмысленных проверок
void contains_null_check_stage2(int *P) {
  if (P == 0)   // проверка на null имеет смысл, оставляем.
    return;
  *P = 4;
}
```

Но если оптимизатор реализован по-другому, и выполняет оптимизации в другом порядке, мы получаем следующее:

```
// после удаления бессмысленных проверок
void contains_null_check_stage1(int *P) {
  int dead = *P;
  if (false)  // в этой точке P был разыменован, он не может быть nullptr
    return;
  *P = 4;
}
```

и затем:

```
// после удаления мёртвого кода
void contains_null_check_stage2(int *P) {
  //int dead = *P;
  //if (false)
  //  return;
  *P = 4;
}
```

Что произошло на первом этапе? Для компилятора разыменование nullptr есть undefined behaviour, он **имеет право** предполагать, что этого не происходит. Значит, видя строчку `int dead = *P;`, он имеет право предполагать, что `P` не `nullptr`. Поэтому проверку на `nullptr` он может выкинуть как бессмысленную.

Для многих нормальных программистов удаление проверки на `nullptr` из этой функции выглядит очень странно (и они наверное даже отправят баг разработчикам компилятора). Тем не менее, оба варианта компиляции соответствуют стандарту на 100%, и каждая из приведённых оптимизаций очень важна для производительности.

Несмотря на то, что этот пример кажется слишком простым и надуманным, подобные вещи часто случаются неявно в результате подстановки inline-функций: подстановка даёт возможность большей оптимизации. Это означает, что если оптимизатор решает включить функцию в другую функцию, большое количество локальных оптимизаций тут же включаются в игру, и это может поменять поведение кода. Это тоже разрешено по стандарту, и очень важно для хорошей производительности скомпилированного кода.

---

Мораль этой истории — компилятор C больше не является «высокоуровневым ассемблером», и выполняемый код может быть очень далёк от буквального, построчного выполнения того, что вы написали.

Comment: Не уверен, что пример хорош. Думаю, предполагается, что модуль ядра с этим кодом обязан компилироваться с такими флагами компиляции, которые исключают рассмотренную оптимизацию. Не знаю зачем, но видимо в коде, вызывающем contains_null_check требуется, чтобы при p == 0 отработал какой-то обработчик прерывания, причем именно естественным образом, т.е. когда он вызывается аппаратурой (могу предположить, что это как-то связано с MMU, TLB и т.п.)

Comment: @avp: Это одна из причин, по которым ядро компилируется с `-O2` :)

Comment: @avp: А сам баг попробую найти.

Comment: @avp: Кажется, вот этот баг: http://lwn.net/Articles/341773/

Comment: Толком не разобрался я с этим длиннющим обсуждением. Вынес только, что скорее всего мое предположение о вызове обработчика таким экстравагантным способом неверно.

Comment: @avp: Пытаюсь разобрать вот это: https://grsecurity.net/~spender/exploits/exploit2.txt

Comment: Вопрос по c++, а ответ по c. Безобразие.

Comment: @alexolut: А в чём отличие для данного случая?

Comment: @VladD с точки зрения итога, т.е. `UB`, отличий нет. Но `c` и `c++` это разные языки, хотя и с общими корнями. В общем, не совсем корректно ставить диагноз одному пациенту на основании анализов другого. Даже если они живут в одном доме.

Comment: @alexolut: Но ведь все рассуждения, за исключением последнего абзаца, равно относятся как к C, так и к C++, разве нет?

Comment: @VladD в целом, да. Только вот Linux - это `c`, а `nullptr` - это `c++`. Я придерживаюсь точки зрения, что лучше их не смешивать. По-крайней мере, при обсуждении внутреннего устройства.

Answer (score 3):

`nullptr` является литералом, имеющим тип `std::nullptr_t`. Для данного типа операция разыменования отсутствует, поэтому в исходной формулировке:

> Что происходит при разыменовании `nullptr`?

ответом будет: [**ошибка компиляции**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/iyoW4zDFNFbPMIZY), с выводом соответствующего сообщения:

> error: indirection requires pointer operand ('nullptr_t' invalid)

Если же речь о разыменовании нативного указателя на некоторый тип `T`, которому предварительно было присвоено значение `nullptr`:

```
T* p = nullptr;
*p;
```

то тут происходит неявное преобразование из типа `std::nullptr_t` в тип `T*` с последующим разыменованием. И вот такое действие уже **приводит к неопределенному поведению**.